# React state value that does not cause a rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to update and keep track of variables that aren't required to be in `useCallback`'s dependency array.

I'm currently using a pagination system that will load x amount of data and if there's more data, give the front end the next page number to request for more data. It's a bit awkward but it's all I can use.

If I were to have `projectId` and `pageNumber` as state values, the `useCallback` hook would want them in its dependency array, which will cause an infinite loop. That's no good. So I'm instead using `useRef` which apparently is the way around this.

The problem is that while those values update throughout the component, the value in `scrollToLoadMore` never changes. It is always 0. I assume this is React being clever and thinking the function never needs to rerender as it doesn't contain a state value but that's kinda getting in my way.

So if I were to throw a `console.log(pageNumber)` in the middle of the component, it would correctly show the new value. But the function never changes.

Sorry if this was unclear, hopefully the code will better illustrate what I'm getting at. This is quite cut down, but I believe shows off all the relevant bits.

```
const IssueList: FunctionalComponent = () => {
    const projectId = useRef(0);
    const pageNumber = useRef(0);

    const fetchIssues = useCallback(
        async (append = false) => {
            const result = ...

            if (...) {
                if (append) {
                    // I set a component state value here
                } else {
                    // or here.
                }
                projectId.current = result.nextResource.projectId;
                pageNumber.current = result.nextResource.pageNumber;
            }
        },
        [...],
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchIssues();
    }, [fetchIssues]);

    console.log(pageNumber.current); // Changes to '1' as expected

    function scrollToLoadMore(e: HTMLDivElement): void {
        // pageNumber.current always === 0
        if (e.scrollHeight - e.scrollTop === e.clientHeight && pageNumber.current !== 0) {
            fetchIssues(true);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div
            class="md:mr-4 rounded bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-lg overflow-y-scroll issuesList"
            onScroll={(e): void => scrollToLoadMore(e.target as HTMLDivElement)}
        >
            ...
        </div>
    );
};

export default IssueList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, ended up being a block of code that I thought was unrelated. It's not that the value I wanted didn't update in my `scrollToLoadMore` function, but the value was changed back to 0 before it could be used.